# Why can't I iterate over `performance.timing` using Underscore or lodash?

Tags: javascript, performancecounter

Why does this:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var myObj = {
        'hello':'world',
        'more':'things'
    };
    
    _.each(myObj, function(value, key){
        console.log(key, value);
    });
    
    // why doesn't this output anything?    
    _.each(performance.timing, function(value, key){
        console.log(key, value);
    });
    
    // just to make sure we can
    console.log(performance.timing);
},500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

output this:

```
> hello world
> more things
> PerformanceTiming {}
```

I would expect the object's keys and values to get output the same as `myobj`.

Underscore:  http://jsfiddle.net/a43vb7gd/1/
lodash:  http://jsfiddle.net/mkxncwax/1/

Reproduces on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 and Firefox 38.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

[image: screenshot of code and console output]

Comment: It works well on Chrome

Comment: What browser[s] are you having an issue in?

Comment: Just edited your code to use a snipplet and I see what you see with chrome on OSX

Comment: @mshaaban It reproduces for me on Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04.  Added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is host object weirdness.  `Object.keys(performance.timing)` returns and empty array.  Also code behaves differently if it's run on the page vs run in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Because performance.timing is just an instance of `PerformanceTiming` class. Which means `performance.timing.__proto__` is equal to `PerformanceTiming.prototype`.

`performance.timing` has no own properties but all inherited properties from `PerformanceTiming.prototype`. You can get all of its properties by:

```js
Object.keys(PerfomanceTiming.prototype)
```

or

```js
Object.keys(performance.timing.__proto__)
```